# Swift 2.0 как применить autureleasepool

Tags: swift

Имеется конструкция с перезапуском по таймеру, каждый перезапуск для iPhone 6 +
добавляет потребление памяти около 12 Мб (что справедливо, но вредно) и эти объекты
где-то там и болтаются, не взирая на эту самую ARC... пока не устаканятся где-то  на
уровне 412 Мб ...многовато однако...(но ОШ нет)...висит на массиве... iOS экономит и
не хочет туда-сюда...

```
/***********************  background  *************************/
 weak var imBackGroundView: UIImageView?

 func runMe0002() {

 if(self.imBackGroundView == nil)

 {
 self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named:
    background[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(background.count)))])!)
    //background = массив тип String        
 }
```

/*********************************************************************/
         var imBackGroundView: Int? // ОШ нет...

-конечно из self.view.backgroundColor... вряд ли что извлечется, хотя по идее из массива
должно выходить что-то типа Int...пробуем...

```
   if(self.imBackGroundView == 0) {  

  /***** контрольная анимация (проверена) *****/

        use = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(360, 300, 600,80))
        use.image = UIImage(named: "use0002.png")
        self.view.addSubview(use)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.8, animations: {
        self.use.frame = CGRect(x: -670, y: 300, width: 600, height: 80) }, completion: nil)

    }  // скобка if */

   if (self.imBackGroundView == "bk0002.jpg") {

        use = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(360, 300, 600,80))
        use.image = UIImage(named: "use0002.png")
        self.view.addSubview(use)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.8, animations: {
        self.use.frame = CGRect(x: -670, y: 300, width: 600, height: 80) }, completion: nil)
    }  // скобка if */

  if (self.imBackGroundView == "bk0002@2x.jpg") {

        use = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(360, 300, 600,80))
        use.image = UIImage(named: "use0002.png")
        self.view.addSubview(use)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.8, animations: {
        self.use.frame = CGRect(x: -670, y: 300, width: 600, height: 80) }, completion: nil)

    }  // скобка if */

     // во всех случаях сюда нет ни ответа ни привета...а надо бы...но и ОШ нет...
     // скорее всего и autoReleasepool не сработает , что и получилось...

     /************************ autoReleasepool *************************/
 if (imBackGroundView != nil) {

    for i in 0...100 {

    autoreleasepool() { /* Do a search that creates a lot of temporary objects. */

        //let data = NSData.dataWithContentsOfFile (options: nil) // дает ОШ, ожидает тип String...
        NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval (0.5)

         // imBackGroundView  retain  /* Keep match around. */

  } // скобка autorelease
  } // скобка for        
  }  // скобка if

  else {
      print("не хочу...") // исправно печатает на каждом цикле...
      }
  под Objctive-C много пояснений, но не применились...сколько напряженно не морщил лоб...
```

Comment: вы б может сначала leaks посмотрели, я думаю оттуда вам больше информации получится извлечь

Comment: leaks смотрел...потом просто сократил массив до 2х штучек и стало ясно откуда тянет, даже без перехода от leaks в xCode...но как расправиться не представляю...все, что нашел - об Objective-C и на прямую не отрабатывается...выборка рекомендаций рядом...@MaxMikheyenko

Comment: а вот это вот что? `// imBackGroundView  retain  /* Keep match around. */`

Comment: это остатки от найденных рекомендаций...пробовал...хотел все это сюда вставить - система ругается...

Comment: есть рекомендация под cache но довольно громоздко и не везде рекомендуется...

Comment: обычно если у вас ARC надо следить за прямым использованием core foundation (например CFStringRef), поскольку ARC не знает что с ними делать, и ваш этот autoreleasepool скорее всего надо руками делать retain/release.

Comment: под Swift очень мало советов...буду искать...но все-таки, а вот пробу по анимации можно все же как-то запустить...почему система не реагирует, но и не ругается...интересно, что не хватает...или как-то через NSObject можно выйти = ?

Comment: вы бы показали код, который можно скомпилировать и у себя запустить, было бы проще разобраться

Comment: то, что здесь в принципе компилируется, нужны просто имаджи...подготовил рабочую опробованную выборку для компиляции zip = 2Мбт со всеми имажами и принадлежностями...svalka0001.swift коды разных примеров...куда закинуть=? - дернуло меня этим заниматься - теперь приходится личным примером убеждать юное поколение в не поймешь чем...в принципе что-то уже получается, но такое потребление ресурсов не пропустят...@MaxMikheyenko

Comment: залейте на гитхаб

Comment: github зарегился...но upload не хочет...буду разбираться

Comment: тогда проще на любую файловую свалку залить

Comment: яндекс пропускает до 30мб  тестировка соб па=мик........ко англкл отправлено...@MaxMikheyenko

Answer (score 3):

У Вас утечка здесь

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.8, animations: {
        self.use.frame = CGRect(x: -670, y: 300, width: 600, height: 80) }, completion: nil)
```

Вы используете сильную ссылку в замыкании, что приводит к утечке. Лучше писать

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.8, animations: { [weak self] in
        self?.use.frame = CGRect(x: -670, y: 300, width: 600, height: 80) }, completion: nil)
```

Ну или

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.8, animations: { [unowned self] in
        self.use.frame = CGRect(x: -670, y: 300, width: 600, height: 80) }, completion: nil)
```

Comment: то, что в ответе - это просто коды контрольной анимации - посмотреть срабатывает или нет...основное потребление памяти - image бекграунда - при сокращении кол-ва обновлений из массива до 2х - потребление памяти снижается в разы...нужно что-то вроде autoReleasepool как-то применить, но не получается...@good в любом случае благодарю за внимание...